# How to manage downtime in the Android app

Tags: android

I am working on app where target users are more than 30K so it is very important for us to keep app always working and `server` up because `server` send a result to android app in `JSON`. But In worst case if server by any reason down then it can keep everything in pathetic situation.

I want whenever any case server get down then I should show one `Activity` that demonstrates that our `server` is down.

Should I ping to server in few minutes from `Android` app to see whether `server` is up or not ?

How I can handle the downtime feature in my `Android` app ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you connect to your server, you will receive a result (even if a 500 error) or a failure. You can then implement something from here (ex: you get N consecutive failures -> show error screen to the user and keep trying in the background)

Comment: actually this is a HTTP error code. In case of server down, he will get a `ConnectTimeoutException` instead

Comment: Don't ping the server just to see if it is up, find out when you have useful information to retrieve or push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way would be using a 2nd backend, that has a stable connection and pings your server regularly. Before making an actual server request, the app queries that backend to check server status.

General approach (not 100% reliable!):

- make sure the device has an active data connection before making any requests
- check the current network type and adjust connection and SO timeouts (e.g. increase them on EDGE)
- if the device has an active data connection, timeout values are high enough, but you keep getting a `ConnectTimeoutException` you can assume that the server is down

P.S. the `ConnectTimeoutException` applies for an Apache `HttpClient`. Otherwise, that will most likely be a [`java.net.ConnectException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ConnectException.html).

And of course, I would suggest you to test any approach in a test environment where you can emulate the server being down.

That is how I did it for my background threads in a networking app: you catch an `Exception` while connecting using a `try-catch`. In a helper class I created a static "checkError" method, in case an `Exception` occurs, it is passed to this method. Then I check the `Exception` type using `instanceof` as condition and handle it appropriately.

Comment: `ConnectionTimeOutException` sometimes can occur in worst case even my server is not down.

Comment: and I have a code of http call in my project at multiple places. so do I check this to all location `ConnectionTimeOut`. Isn't there a way to check this at only one location ?

Comment: @Williams sure it can always occur, so you'll need to count how many times it has occurred in the same thread and define a threshold of "server down". I extended my answer

Comment: so do I check this to all location ConnectionTimeOut. Isn't there a way to check this at only one location ?

Comment: see my edited answer. U need 1 method that checks it and you call this method inside the `catch` clause everywhere this `Exception` is possible.